# Import Handlers - App Route with Flask

Tags: python, url-routing, flask

My File Directory:

```
app/
app.py
app/server/
   views.py
```

I don't get any import errors with views, but I am not able to URL route to Views - I can only do it from app.py - how can I fix this issue? I've been stuck on this for 6 hours.

Code from app.py - how I import views

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'server'))
import views
```

And my url routing seems fine, so I am not sure where the problem lies:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    doSomething()
```

---

I feel the problem is more to do with url routing than importing files though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `from views import *` instead of `import views`.

Also, instead of doing `sys.path.append`, add an empty file named `__init__.py` to the server directory, and you should be able to do something like `from server.views import *`.

**Solution**: Also make sure your view import is towards the bottom of your app file, below the app initialization and config and such.

Comment: Nope that did not work - I think the import is ok - I have a feeling to do with url routing - app.route(etc.) but I am not sure what to do

Comment: Your routing decorators should be fine if it looks like what you pasted. Also make sure your view import is towards the bottom of your app file, below the app initialization and config and such. You're not getting any exceptions, right?

Comment: can you turn debugging on using app.debug = True and then see what error msg comes up if any ?

Comment: Thank you so much Anorov!!!

The problem was that the import statement was at the top of the file before app was initialized - I've always done it that way so I never figured something was wrong - still new to web app dev, I guess.

Comment: I've added your comments' solution to your response - please accept it.

Comment: @RohitRayudu Keep in mind that, in terms of readability, using `from package import *` is generally a [really, *really* bad idea](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules).

Comment: @kuyan I agree in general. For Flask though, I believe `from views import *` is pretty much the accepted way of including views defined in a separate file.